# How to create a popup in JS when a user belongs to a group?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have added a Javascript in the A domain (client) that saves in an md5 some characteristics of the visitors browser to the mySQL database of B domain (mine) using JSONP.

This allows me to create a unique (90%) fingerprint for each visitor and track their behavior on the site.

In mySQL I have created a column group and grouped some visitors with the same value 1. So it is something like this

```
visitor    group
bhrth44    1
btrsbtr    1
ergrgeg    1
gergerg    2
```

What I need to do is to display to those who have group = 1 a message in the A domain (client) when they visit the site again, even a small dot at the footer to test if this works.

What I can do, is to send through jsonp the visitor ID and be checked through the mySQL and return the group number to the A domain (client).

So I can know that if the visitor belongs to a group or not. My question is how My external JS is minified, I do not know if this helps somewhere.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach seems a little overcomplicated.

Your question seems to boil down to how do I know if a user has already visited my site?

What characteristics of a User's browser will be unique?? Surely lots of people have Internet Explorer 10 with the same User agent strings etc. Maybe even visiting from the same URL etc.

A more common approach would be to store either a cookie or some data in the local storage of the Users browser identifying them as a returning user.

You can look for the presence of this cookie or local storage setting and modify your home page appropriately.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but what i asked is not how to correctly identify the users but on how to show a message to a specific group